# AHK: How to sensibly handle modifier keys and allow "spamming" of hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Currently for any hotkey I want to apply and want it to act sensibly I need to redo the modifier key in the end of the shortcut manually. (see `CtrlDown` at the end of `^g`)

The intent is to map JUST ctrl+g to the sequence Ctrl+t, Alt+g and then be able to keep holding ctrl without releasing and have the hotkey work again after pressing g

```
^g::Send {CtrlDown}{t}{CtrlUp}{AltDown}{g}{AltUp}{CtrlDown} ; Alt + G - new tab in new group
```

I don't want it to pass modifiers or change any other key. just remap into a sequence

How would I be able to simplify this code and keep it "spammable" without releasing the ctrl key?
This hotkey standalone works.

```
^g::Send ^t!g
```

but sadly

```
^f::^g ; traverse search results with ctrl+f
^g::Send ^t!g
```

when I use these 2 lines it doesn't work but adding a send on `^f` fixes the issue.

```
^f::Send ^g ; traverse search results with ctrl+f
^g::Send ^t!g
```

further more, If I now add an ifwinactive pragma, it again, doesn't work as intended

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe msedge.exe

^f::Send ^g ; traverse search results with ctrl+f
^g::Send ^t!g
```

any clue why? I have more hotkeys defined not just these 2, it doesn't work when I add my other hotkeys or pragmas. I don't understand why there is a correlation to begin with.